# how to remove the message: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I run my Kotlin project and this message appears before the output. How I can remove this message? (I use Linux and Intellij IDEA)